# inline-block property of css not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place 2 blocks inside 1 parent block.

```
.childright {
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 140px;
    width: 405px;
    position: relative;
}
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;

    background-color: blue;
border-radius: 4px;
height: 150px;
width: 500px;
}
.childleft {
margin-bottom: 5px;
border-radius: 4px;
height: 60px;
width: 60px;
margin-left: 5px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #EEE;
vertical-align: middle;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(70%);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent" >
<div class="childleft"> </div>
<div class="childright"> </div>
</div>
```

Above works.

But the following places childright below childleft.

```
<div class="span2">
  <img class="span3" src="http://www.someimage.jpg" />
  <p class="span1"> Random text</p>
</div>
```

Can you tell me what's going wrong here? I am new to CSS.

Edit: Here is the webpage where its not working correctly.  http://www.ablueheart.com/uncategorized/2013-11-13/test

Comment: It is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/o0ckcx6f/. Explain your problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: Its working fine, what you expect ?

Comment: In that case some existing CSS must be interfering right?

Comment: Here is the webpage where its not working, don't know why? If anyone can take a look, it would be great help.
http://www.ablueheart.com/uncategorized/2013-11-13/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra blank `p` tag in the `span2` div  remove it .

```
<div class="span2">
  <img width="60" height="60" src="http://i0.wp.com/www.ablueheart.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Jose-Mourinho-thumb.jpg?w=474" class="span3"></p>
<p class="span1"> text I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away!I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away!I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away! I</p>
</div>
```

.

```
<div class="span2">
  <img width="60" height="60" src="http://i0.wp.com/www.ablueheart.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Jose-Mourinho-thumb.jpg?w=474" class="span3">
<p class="span1"> text I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away!I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away!I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away! I</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have any extra tags.

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/OLoB35-DYroIYt1fzmdUfMEI3SCsc-odh2g3BuWjiiLHBximC7VvFrLtX0PhQCHeyKVCtTNlcPbPZUMpykCpqbXwEuo=w1332-h511

Comment: Great find! In mozilla also I am able to see the tags. It seems some space was being translated as <p> tag (even in the code view in wordpress). This explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on inline-block gives uncertain results because spaces between tags behave like margins, and depending on your font-size or letter-spacing, .childright could or couldn't have enough space.

Adding this to your css should fix your problem:

```
.childleft, .span3 { float:left; }
.childright, .span1 { float:right; }
```

Comment: Cheers. Your solution works. A quick question though, my existing p tag has margin-bottom: 24px;
I tried putting margin-bottom: 0px !important; in .childright but that didn't override it. Any idea how negate this margin-bottom (it is pushing the childright by a 24 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

i made some modification in class "span1","span2","span3" and remove property "transform: translateY(70%);" in class "span3" :[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzdhvhsg/)

```css
.span3{
  background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
   
   
   
    width: 60px;
}
div.span3{
 
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 41px;

}
.span2 {
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 500px;
}
.span1 {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 405px;
}
div.span1{
   margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span2">
<div class="span3" > <img width="60" height="60" class="span3" src="http://i0.wp.com/www.ablueheart.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Jose-Mourinho-thumb.jpg?w=474"></div>
<div class="span1"> 
  <p class="span1" style="margin: 0px;"> text I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away!I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away!I’m vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away! I</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will give this a try in the evening. If this works, it will be great.